# One row takes 8 kilobytes but datalength from 1 row is 4532 bytes

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I have a table that has a lot of nvarchar columns. Some dummy data were inserted (each row has 4532 bytes currently - It is sum of datalength(column) ).
It reached already 10 GB - max size for data file in SQL Express. 
I execute the below:

```
execute sp_spaceused [mytable]
```

when I divide data / rows => 8 kilobytes

New inserts are not possible and they finish with

```
Could not allocate space for object 'mytable' in database ...
```

Each page supposed to have still 3660 bytes free. How can I use this space?
I use SQL Express, so I cannot add there more space. it seems that new inserts are not able to use left space in pages. Can I force somehow it to split my data in two pages?

Comment: rows cannot be split across pages. If you put 4532, your row is already using more than 4532, probably 4600-4700. There is only ~3300 bytes left and this is not enough for a row.

Comment: if possible you could [split up `[mytable]`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/a-simple-start-table-creation-best-practices/) into 2 or more tables to optimize page utilization

Comment: @ughai - the OP has indicated that they're running into the 10GB size limit in express. That's a DB size limit, not a table one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - You are right but splitting up would help get almost 2x rows before OP hits the 10GB limit in express

Comment: If you are that close to the space limit of Express you have lost in the long term anyway. You need a totally different approach. Maybe sharding across databases.

Comment: Maybe save in binary as compressed or UTF??

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I just want to know if it's possible somehow use these 3300 bytes that are reserved for future updates.